# How can I get comments from swc_ecma_parser

Tags: rust, swc-compiler

```
use swc_common::sync::Lrc;
use swc_common::{FileName, SourceMap};
use swc_ecma_parser::{Parser, StringInput, Syntax};

fn main() {
    let cm: Lrc<SourceMap> = Default::default();

    // Real usage
    // let fm = cm
    //     .load_file(Path::new("test.js"))
    //     .expect("failed to load test.js");
    let fm = cm.new_source_file(
        FileName::Custom("test.js".into()),
        "
        // test
        function foo() {}
        "
        .into(),
    );

    let ts_config = swc_ecma_parser::TsConfig {
        decorators: true,
        // dynamic_import: true,
        tsx: true,
        ..Default::default()
    };

    let mut parser = Parser::new(
        Syntax::Typescript(ts_config),
        StringInput::from(&*fm),
        Default::default(),
    );

    let module = parser
        .parse_typescript_module()
        .expect("failed to parser module");

    module.body.into_iter().for_each(|module_item| {
        println!("{:?}", module_item);
    });

}
```

I am trying to parse script file and do some modification to the AST, and then generate new code based on modifed AST. But when I do a simple test, swc_ecma_parser doesn't provide comment node. See below output of println:

> Stmt(Decl(Fn(FnDecl { ident: Ident { span: Span { lo: BytePos(35), hi: BytePos(38), ctxt: #0 }, sym: "foo", optional: false }, declare: false, function: Function { params: [], decorators: [], span: Span { lo: BytePos(26), hi: BytePos(43), ctxt: #0 }, body: Some(BlockStmt { span: Span { lo: BytePos(41), hi: BytePos(43), ctxt: #0 }, stmts: [] }), is_generator: false, is_async: false, type_params: None, return_type: None } })))

It only has the function declarion node, the comment `// test` is stripped.

How can I get the comment, and change the comment `// test` to `// modified comment`. Thanks

Comment: The comments are not part of the AST.  They won't be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are indeed not part of the AST, but the parser handles them separately. The third argument of [`Parser::new`](https://rustdoc.swc.rs/swc_ecma_parser/struct.Parser.html#method.new) is `comments: Option<&'a dyn Comments>`. In your code you provide `Default::default()` here, which is simply `None` for an `Option`, suppressing any comment parsing. You can instead create one of the implementations of the [`Comments` trait](https://rustdoc.swc.rs/swc_common/comments/trait.Comments.html), such as [`SingleThreadedComments`](https://rustdoc.swc.rs/swc_common/comments/struct.SingleThreadedComments.html):

```rust
let comments: swc_common::comments::SingleThreadedComments = Default::default();
let mut parser = Parser::new(
    Syntax::Typescript(ts_config),
    StringInput::from(&*fm),
    Some(&comments),
);
```

After invoking the parser, `comments` should be updated (the API uses a shared reference for [reasons](https://rustdoc.swc.rs/swc_common/comments/trait.Comments.html#implementation-notes)). You should be able to mutably iterate through the comments using [`borrow_all_mut`](https://rustdoc.swc.rs/swc_common/comments/struct.SingleThreadedComments.html#method.borrow_all_mut).

Finally, it seems like [`swc::Compiler::print`](https://docs.rs/swc/latest/swc/struct.Compiler.html#method.print) is the method you will want to use to convert the AST back into code. Again, this method accepts `comments: Option<&dyn Comments>` as its last argument.

Comment: Thanks, this is really help. I can get and modify comments.  But I encounter a new problem, the multiple line comments will be concated with code in one line, I'm not sure how to fix this, maybe adding a new line node (if has) to manaully fix it.

```
/*
  * this is a multiple line
  * the second line
*/
class A {}
```

will become

```
/*
  * this is a multiple line
  * the second line
*/ class A {}  // <-- The end of comment should have a newline, but it doesn't
```

Comment: @tjfdfs (You can't use block code syntax in comments, so it's hard to tell what the problem is.) It sounds like [this issue](https://github.com/swc-project/swc/issues/7492)?